# Trouble calling columns from an excel file

Tags: matlab

I am trying to call an excel file and run it into my function to output an array of calculated velocities given time, angle, and radius in MATLAB

This is my code so far:

```
function [vR,vTheta,v] = temp_func(time,radius,theta)
vR = (radius(2:1:end) - radius(1:1:end-1))./((time(2:1:end) - time(1:1:end-1)))
vTheta = (theta(2:1:end)*(pi./180) - theta(1:1:end-1)*(pi./180))./((time(2:1:end) - time(1:1:end-1)))
v = ((vR(1:1:end)).^2.+(vTheta(1:1:end)).^2).^(1/2)

end
```

This code works if I were to call something like `temp_func([0 1 2], [0 1 3], [0 0 180])`.

However, I need to call the columns in a 1083x3 excel file (called GPSdata) and I am unsure how directly call for this matrix. I've tried `temp_func(GPSdata(1:end,1),GPSdata(1:end,2),GPSdata(1:end,3))`

To call the first, second, and third columns respectively. But I get this error:

```
Error using  () 
Subscripting into a table using one subscript (as in t(i)) is not supported. Specify a row subscript and a variable
subscript, as in t(rows,vars). To select variables, use t(:,i) or for one variable t.(i). To select rows, use t(i,:).
```